# What is a "Slime Chunk" and how do you find it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to make a slime farm, so I looked at the requirements for a slime to spawn, and it said I needed to find a "Slime Chunk". If anyone knows how to find this, please tell me.

Answer (score 4):

#### Slimes

> Slimes are bouncy cube-shaped hostile mobs that spawn in the swamp,
> and occasionally, deep underground.
>
> Slimes spawn in the Overworld in specific "slime chunks" below layer
> 40 regardless of light levels. They can also spawn in swamp biomes
> between layers 50 and 70 in light levels of 7 or less.
>
> ##### **"Slime chunks"**
>
> Slimes spawn throughout the world (except mushroom
> islands) below layer 40 regardless of light level, but only in certain
> chunks, 1 in 10 of all chunks. These "slime chunks" are determined
> pseudo-randomly by combining their chunk coordinates with the seed of
> the world.

*Source: [Minecraft Gamepedia: Slime](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Slime)*

#### What is a chunk?

> Chunks are 256 block tall 16 × 16 segments of the Minecraft worlds.
> Chunks are the method used by the world generator to divide maps into
> manageable pieces.

*Source: [Minecraft Gamepedia: Chunk](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk)*

#### Conclusion

In short, you can find your slimes underground, but they only spawn in certain parts of the map. To find out were these parts are exactly, you could use [a site like this](http://chunkbase.com/apps/slime-finder).

Answer (score 0):

In Java Edition, you can go into chat and do "/seed," which will show your seed. Then, you can go to https://www.chunkbase.com/apps/slime-finder and enter the seed (copy the seed by clicking on it) and it will show the coordinates that you will find it at.